# How to access parent component type in child component?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

In a child component, how can I access a reference to the parent component? I need to perform specific operations in the child if it's nested within a specific type of parent.

```
<MyParentComponent>
    <MyChildComponent></MyChildComponent>
</MyParentComponent>
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a lot of ways to do this.

If you only want one property / method from the parent, you can just pass a parameter for that property / method as you can see in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#parameters).

If you want the whole parent you can use a `CascadingValue` and pass `this`.

e.g.

MyParentComponent.razor

```
<CascadingValue Value="this">
    @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>
```

And in the `MyChildComponent`, you access it by `CascadingParameter`.

```
[CascadingParameter]
public MyParentComponent MyParentComponent { get; set; }
```

This will be a good way to get the parent reference if the child component isn't directly a child of the parent component and you don't want to pass multiple parameters across nested components.